# How to update but if field is empty not

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0

I need to run a save/update query but only update those fields that aren't empty. My form contains a FILE field and if I don't upload any file then when the save() is executed this field goes blank even if previous data is presented so how can I save/updated but onlye the fields with content to update?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you need to previously test if the data is empty or not and **unset** it in this case.

```
if ($this->data['file'] == "") {
    unset($this->data['file']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly but just one thing is not in my model where I need to check this is in my controller :)

Comment: Depends on your application, but I would let this task to my model. Anyway, as long as it works.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You always can add a condition which checks if the user uploads a file or not.
If not , select the current value in the database for that file and update it with the old value.

For example:

```
$update['description'] = $_POST['description']; //just another field
if($_POST['file']['name'] == "") //check if there's a new file
  $update['filename'] = $this->book->file_name; //current file name
else
  $update['filename'] = $_POST['file']['name']; //new file name in case the user uploaded a new file

$this->book->update($update); //update no matter what
```